# Offset pandas datetime series by months

Tags: pandas

I've a pandas df with dates and index like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2021-09-30','2021-12-31','2021-12-31'],
            'idx':[1,2,3]})
```

I'd like to move the dates bu n months using the idx column.

I converted the column dates using the datetime format:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

And then I tried to use some function like MonthEnd or DateOffset from pandas.tseries.offsets but they only work with an integer (and not a list).
Do you have any suggestions?

The final result should be the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'newdates': ['2021-10-31','2022-02-28','2022-03-31']})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With `DateOffset / MonthEnd`, you can try this:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset, MonthEnd
df.dates + df.idx.map(lambda m: DateOffset(months=m)) + MonthEnd(0)

0   2021-10-31
1   2022-02-28
2   2022-03-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: this shows a good method to achieving it, just needs end month day adjustment

Comment: @Jayvee Just realize it's not the MonthEnd in my solution, Made an edit to reflect that - thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Cool, this is much more straight forward than my solution without MonthEnd

Answer (score 1):

Using @Psidom method just adjusting the month end date:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

df['new_dates']=(df.dates+DateOffset(days=1) + df.idx.map(lambda m: DateOffset(months=m)))-DateOffset(days=1)



    dates   idx     new_dates
0   2021-09-30  1   2021-10-31
1   2021-12-31  2   2022-02-28
2   2021-12-31  3   2022-03-31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['new_dates'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['dates'] + relativedelta(month=x['idx']), axis=1)
```